# SQLite strings filtering

Tags: sqlite

for example my "select" query returns rows:

- "asd/1"
- "asd/2"

but for me rows "asd/1", "asd/2" represents the same value. Is any way to truncate strings to such result: (i want to truncate everything after '/' inclusive)

- "asd"

??

Comment: You can use a combination of the `instr` function and the substring functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work

`select distinct substr(column_name, 1, instr(column_name, '/') - 1) from table_name`

This get back `column_name` up to the first '/' in the string (but not including the slash because of the -1) and then only give back the unique results (because of the `distinct` keyword)